# Pass parameter to EventEmitter.on method in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have just  started exploring node.js and below is situation with me while learning events handling in node.js.

I have an event 'loop' and a function 'myLoopHandler' attached to it using the method

```
eventEmitter.on('loop',myLoopHandler);
```

And the myLoopHandler is defined as follows:

```
var myLoopHandler = function(){
for(i=1;i<=30;i++)
    console.log(i);
}
```

And then I emit the event 'loop' :

```
eventEmitter.emit('loop');
```

How do I pass some parameter to the myLoopHandler function in eventEmitter.on method?

I am open to any other way of  achieving the same.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

just do

```
emitter.emit(eventName[, ...args])
```

where args is the arguments to emit

this is an example

```
const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();
myEmitter.on('event', function(a, b) {
  console.log(a, b, this);
  // Prints:
  //   a b MyEmitter {
  //     domain: null,
  //     _events: { event: [Function] },
  //     _eventsCount: 1,
  //     _maxListeners: undefined }
});
myEmitter.emit('event', 'a', 'b');
```

source [NodeJS docs](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html)

Comment: This worked. But  here I am defining the function in the 'on' method itself. But is there a way to define the function separately and then use it along with passing parameters.

Comment: var myLoopHandler = function(a, b) would get the values a and b if that is what you are asking